# Change variable type from string to binary

Tags: php, string, binary, variable-types

I have a string like :

```
  $str = "01110001";
```

and I want to change its type to binary with :

```
$bin = (binary) $str;
```

( because I want to inverse it ) **But**, when I try to `var_dump($bin)`, I get :

```
string(8) "01110001"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary is not datatype. Hence you can not cast with it.

However you can representation of binary to decimal using [bindec](http://php.net/bindec) function.

```
$bin = (string)bindec($str);
```

**Note:** Every number is stored as binary in memory. So you dont have specifically convert it to binary. Just use `bindec` and it'll convert it to number. Then it'll be stored in 4 byte integer as binary. If its string then for every digit it'll use 8 bytes.

Comment: I don't want to change the type to integer. I have the binary mode of a variable but its type is string, I want to change the type to binary so I can inverse it

Comment: You can not change it to binary. You need to change it to numeric type. I have updated my answer.

Comment: but I need to act with this like binary, I want to inverse the variable : `1010001 --> 0101110` with `~`

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im 's answer is correct but you don't need to cast to string if you need an integer. Just `$bin = bindec($str);` should do it.

Comment: @this.lau_ Are you guys listening to me? I dont want integer. I want binary, I want to inverse the variable like I said in the above comment

Comment: @AlirezaFallah You can inverse the number. Get the integer with bindec and then apply `~`. It'll be inversed. To see the inversed bin use decbin function.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im can you give an example ? I cant use it like you say

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - And what is the first 25 one in the start of the string?